UART Communication Between STM32 and ESP32
I am trying to get my ESP32 and STM32 boards to communicate via UART connection. However, when I run both programs in the Arduino IDE, it (1) doesn't seem to see that the Serial Port is available, and (2) I also am not sure how to access the data from Serial sent from the STM32.
Would anyone be able to help me out here?
The flow of the program is that the STM32 sends data to the ESP32, and the ESP32 receives and displays it.
ESP32 Model - FREENOVE ESP32 Wrover
STM32 Model - STM32 Nucleo F446RE
Here is my STM32 code:
#include <HardwareSerial.h>

HardwareSerial Serial1(PA10 , PB6);

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial1.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  Serial1.print("Sending.... ");
  Serial.println("Sent");
  delay(1000);
}

Here is my ESP32 code:
#include <HardwareSerial.h>

HardwareSerial SerialPort(1);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  SerialPort.begin(115200, SERIAL_8N1, 32, 33);
}

void loop() {
  if (SerialPort.available()) {
    Serial.println("Printing data");
    // Print data from the serial port below
  }
}

Much appreciated!
I tried to run both STM32 and ESP32 programs with the correct wiring, and it appears that the STM32 sends the message, but the ESP32 doesn't receive it?

How exactly do you know what happens and doesn't happen? Your ESP32 should send something to PC right in setup, to signal that its serial works correctly. Similarly, verify that every communication line works as intended and actually sends stuff.

What have you done to verify that you actually have "the correct wiring"? BTW consider using more variation, more descriptive names than just Serial, Serial1 and SerialPort for clarity.
